# Is this safe for a USB Sharing Switch?

Tags: usb

I am making a KVM switch for a single USB port. I found a tutorial for this online, but I am concerned if there is any problem with hooking up VCC like this. Is that alright?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f633PH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There could be since the voltages from two supplies will never be identical and end up fighting  each other.

Comment: Why bother with this when there are know-to-work switches sold on Ebay: https://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/usb-switch-box  These switch all four connections BTW. Switching all connections is often needed as devices initialize when the supply (vcc) is applied. Chances are, what you propose will not work very well.

Comment: why are you connecting Vcc together?

Comment: I've been using it, and it has been working for some hours now. What is the worse that can happen @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: What's the worse to happen @DKNguyen

Comment: @David if you turn one computer off and leave the other on, you could damage one or both of the motherboards, depending on how the 5v line is handled on each on them.

Comment: What @alex.forencich said

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not OK to connect two power supplies like that. Worst thing could be anything like frying two computers, maybe only USB port on motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting the power connections like that is a recipe for bad things. Computers are usually not designed to handle power coming back in the USB 5V pins. If both computers are on, then you will get a small current flowing between the two that's related to the difference in the 5v rail voltages between the machines. However, where you will really run in to problems is when one of the computers is turned off. At best, the turned-off machine will isolate that pin and nothing will happen. Next best case is the turned-off machine will be back-powered through the USB connector and this will trip the overcurrent protection in the other machine. You could see damage on the motherboard of the turned-off machine due to the 5v rail powered in isolation. Worst case, overcurrent protection is not present or does not trip and the cable overheats and starts a fire.

The solution is to switch the power along with the data lines.

Comment: Or connect the power to a single supply separate from either computer (like a via wall-wart). Make sure to share the grounds though so they all have a common reference, but not the Vcc.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the two computers would be OK with their +5v buses being tied together, this switch won't work. The reason is, for most USB devices to detect they are being reconnected, you need to terminate their power. Your switch is not doing it. So, you have to add another relay to switch +5v lines. Then it'd work.

Also, FYI, USB power is usually handled by +5v stand-by line (+5VSB) of the ATX PSU, so that line basically always carries power even when your PC is off.